# How can I add a long text to my fillRect?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jtextarea

I'm working on a program that add pins to a map, the pins are are subclasses to a class that draws a triangle to the map and are clickable, and if you click it shall unfold and show different things like name, text or a picture.

I've one working subclass that creates a rectangle out of the triangle and shows what the name of the place is. For this I used the drawString. But now, to my second subclass, it shall show an description over the place, and the description could be quite long and for this I can't use the drawString, because it only shows on one row, and it will clip my text..

I tried to add the description to a JTextArea, and add that one to a JScrollPane and then I tried to add the scrollpane to the rect area, but that didn't seem to work, because "The method add(JScrollPane) is undefined for the type Graphics"

Here is my super class:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

abstract public class Place extends JComponent {

private String name;
private int x,y;
boolean highlighted = false;
boolean hidden = false;
boolean showed = false;

public Place(int x, int y, String name){
    setBounds(x,y,30,30);
    this.name=name;
    this.x=x-15;
    this.y=y-30;
    Dimension d = new Dimension(30,30);
    setPreferredSize(d);
    setMaximumSize(d);
    setMinimumSize(d);
    addMouseListener(new MouseLis());
}

abstract protected void show(Graphics g);

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
//      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    if(!showed){
    setBounds(x,y,30,30);
    int[] xes = {0,15,30};
    int[] yes = {0,30,0};
    g.fillPolygon(xes, yes, 3);
    } else {
        show(g);


    }



}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}


class MouseLis extends MouseAdapter{
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mev){
        showed = ! showed;
        repaint();
    }
}

}
```

and here is my subclass that doesn't work..

```
class DescPlace extends Place{

private String Description;
private JTextArea desc = new JTextArea(Description);


public DescPlace(int x, int y, String name, String descr){
    super(x,y,name);
    this.Description = descr;
}

protected void show(Graphics g){
    setBounds(getX(), getY(),150,200);
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 200);
    //g.add(new JScrollPane(desc));


}
}
```

Comment: It seems like the question you actually want an answer for is how to show some kind of hovering popup. Is that right? ([*What's an XY problem?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) Consider creating a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same JTextArea and just paint it using Graphics instance

```
desc.setSize(width, height); //define size
desc.paintAll(g); //paint
```

Comment: Worked, thanks :) But I set the color to yellow, it paint it white? :o

Comment: Use desc.setForeground()/setBackground()

Answer (score 2):

You can use a JLabel to do this, using it to display HTML-formatted content.

From Oracle's docs:

> If you want to mix fonts or colors within the text, or if you want **formatting such as multiple lines**, you can use HTML. HTML formatting can be used in all Swing buttons, menu items, labels, tool tips, and tabbed panes, as well as in components such as trees and tables that use labels to render text.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html

**EDIT**
No time to write a thousand words, so here's an example:

```
new JLabel("<html><p>This will</p><br /><p>appear over multiple</p><br /><p>lines</p></html>")
```

The same applies to JToolTip if you go down that route.

Comment: An example is worth a thousand words.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg acknowledged and updated. Thanks for the push.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! No go on answering questions! `<whip/>` ;)